# What Would Be the Most Appropriate Way to Refer to a School Class When Adding People to a Building?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, polymorphism, abstract-class

I was required to apply OOP concepts in every exercise in my Computer Science class. Exercise 7 introduced us to Classes and Objects. We had to create a class called Person and program it to add, remove, and display a person from a 1-dimensional array of 10 persons. Next came in Exercise 8 and 9, where we were introduced to Inheritance and Encapsulation where we had to create a Student class which would inherit from Person, a Teacher class which would inherit from Person, and a Principal class that would inherit from Person. I had to be able to add, remove, and display a list of students/teachers, which works perfectly fine as I completed this.

Our next task was in Exercise 10, which introduced us to Polymorphism and Casting. We had to create a School class which would have a school name, address, and a list of people (max. 300). I have to design a method addPersonToBuilding(Person person), and then modify my previous program so that people are added to the school when they are created. My program (main method) should only require a reference to the School class.

When creating the method addPersonToBuilding, I believe I`d add the student and teacher instance in the people array. I`d create a method to add a student/teacher to the school, and in those methods, add the student/teacher into the people array. The addPersonToBulding method would refer to the add student/teacher to school methods. The method to add PersonToBuliding will be called on for whenever the user chooses to add a student/teacher in the main method.

```js
public class School extends Person {
 
 private String schoolName;
 private String address;
 private String name; 
 private School people[] = new School[300];

 public School() { 
  this.schoolName = "Not Available";
  this.address = "Not Available";
  this.name = "Not Available"; 
 }//end of School()
 
 public School (String schoolName, String address, String prinicpalName) { 
  this.schoolName = schoolName;
  this.address = address;
  this.name = prinicpalName; 
 }//end of School(schoolName, address)
 
 public School (String schoolName, String address, String prinicpalName, School[] people) {  
  this.schoolName = schoolName;
  this.address = address;
  this.name = prinicpalName;
  this.people = people; 
 }//end of School(schoolName, address, people) 
 
 // ---------  include setters and getter methods to access private data ----- 
  
  // I won`t include this because that`s not really an issue I`m having with
 //I`m assuming everyone, including me, knows how they are and what they do 
 
 public boolean addPersonToBuilding (PersonCopy P) { 
  boolean personAdded = false;
  int index = 0;
  return personAdded; 
 }//addPersonToBuilding()
 
 // Create a method to add a student to the school  
 public boolean addStudentToSchool (Student student) { 
  boolean studentAdded = false;
  int index = 0; 
  return studentAdded;  
 }//end of addStudentToSchool(student)
 
 // Create a method to add a teacher to the school 
 public boolean addTeacherToSchool (Teacher teacher) { 
  boolean teacherAdded = false;
  int index = 0;  
  if (addTeacherToSchool(teacher)) {
  }
  return teacherAdded; 
 }//end of addTeacherToSchool(teacher) 
}//end of class School
```

I know what I need to do, but the assumptions I made above the code don`t speak "on the right track" to me. I feel like I`m missing a few details.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While I appreciate that you are only asking for help and not to actually do your homework for you, this question is one we cannot answer without defeating the purpose of this assignment. Please review your class notes and feel free to [edit] this question to be more specific with where you are having difficulty.  Read also: [An open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Thank you! I shortened my question (removed that note where I was roughly brainstorming and noting my thoughts down). How else can I improve my question above for others to defeat the purpose of my assignment?

Comment: Shorten it considerably more.  I would recommend no more than two paragraphs and 20 lines of code.

Comment: I shortened it even more and added a snippet of code as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given Teacher and Student inherrit from Person and you have created the following School class:

```
public School(){
ArrayList<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();

public void addPeople(Person p){
  people.add(p);
}
```

I think an example Main function would help you to solve your Problem:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

   School school = new School();
   Teacher t1 = new Teacher();
   Student s1 = new Student();

   school.addPeople(t1);
   school.addPeople(s1);

   //Polymorphism
   for(Person p: school.getPeople()){
       p.getName(); /* Here the function will be
                       called depending if its a Teacher or Student at runtime */
    }


}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question-and-answer site, not a homework writing service.  Please do not give users reason to believe otherwise.  Thank you.

Comment: He did not just post his homework assignment. He did good effort before and was stuck on a specific spot in my opinion. And as you can see i didn't write his homework, because my code wouldn't even compile. He also followed the advice on how to ask questions about homework described in this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: I am actually a girl, haha. And yes, I did not only post my assignment (I can assure you that most of what I said was not included in the homework instructions). I got clarification from my teacher, and based on what I did and had to do, I wrote everything above in my question. I am stuck on how to begin this,  specifically speaking about the method to add a person to the building. I did list some things I think I`m required to do in terms of logic...